# Find the minimum of the value $n$ such that $(1-0.03)^n<0.03$

Tags: functions, inequality

How can I find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that
$$(1-0.03)^n<0.03$$

without the help of a  computer?

Comment: Are you allowed to use a calculator?  It's not necessary, but I would think a bisection method would quickly find a solution.

Comment: A basic calculator is a computer, so presumably it is disallowed. Then we are back to tables of logarithms. (It can be done by hand, not pleasant.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, a calculator is a computer...also a table of logarithms is generated by a "computer" (even if that computer is human brute force).

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is the binomial expansion: $(1 - 0.03)^n = \sum_0^n \binom{n}{i}(-0.03)^i$--but I don't (at least immediately) see how that would be useful.

Comment: @Jared,the same as you.+1

Comment: If I solved it, I couldn't post the answer (116) anyway, because that would be using a computer.

Comment: Do you have any indication that there is a more elegant solution than somehow evaluating logarithms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(1-0.03)^n<0.03$ we have taking logs: $n\ln(0.97)<\ln(0.03)$ and as both of these logs are negative that gives us: $n>\frac{\ln(0.03)}{\ln(0.97)}$ and so if we are asking for the smallest integer for which the inequalities hold that would be:
$$
n=\left\lceil \frac{\ln(0.03)}{\ln(0.97)}\right\rceil
$$
If you are going to evaluate this numerically it would be best to leave the denominator in the form $\ln(1-0.03)$ as this is well approximated by a small number of terms (1?) of the power series for $\ln(1+x)$ with $x=-0.03$.

For the numerator it looks like you could do something like
$$
\ln(0.03)=-\ln(100/3)=-\ln(1.25^2\times 2^6)+\ln(1.5^2\times2^2)
$$
then use the power series for $\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$ to approximate the logs of $2,\ 1.5,\ 1.25$, but that still leaves a lot of arithmetic...

Answer (score 2):

I would start with $n \log(1-0.03) \lt \log 0.03, n \gt \frac {\log 0.03}{\log(1-0.03)}$.  If you can use log tables, this is an easy divide.  If not, I would hope that the Taylor series for the denominator, $-0.03 -\frac 12 \cdot 0.03^2 \approx  \log (1-0.03)$ is accurate enough. You might even get by with the first term only.  The numerator is harder.  If you know $\log 10$ accurately enough, you can do $\log 0.03=\log 3 - 2 \log 10 = 1 + \log \frac 3e- 2 \log 10$ and get $\log \frac 3e$ from the Taylor series.  I think it is a lot of work without log tables.  If you know $\log 2 \approx 0.693$, you can say $$\frac 1{2^5}=0.3125\\ \log 0.03125\approx (-5)\cdot 0.693 = -3.465\\ \log 0.03 \approx \log (0.03125 \cdot \frac {0.03}{0.03125})\approx -3.465 + \log(1-\frac {0.0125}{0.03125})\approx -3.465 - 0.04$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a shortcut as the numbers $0.97$ and $0.03$ don't appear to have particular properties and the solution is the ratio of their logarithms, not especially easy to compute.

A simple but tedious possibility is by the use of exponential search followed by dichotomy. You start from $0.97^1$ and repeatedly square until you get below the threhold.

$$0.97^2=0.9409,\\
0.97^4=0.9409^2=0.88529\cdots\\\cdots\\
0.97^{64}=0.14236\cdots\\
0.97^{128}=0.02026\cdots$$

So you know that the answer lies between $64$ and $128$. You refine by trying intermediate integers using dichotomy and multiplications by the known powers.

$$0.97^{(64+128)/2}=0.97^{64}\cdot0.97^{32}=0.05371\cdots\\
0.97^{(96+128)/2}=0.97^{96}\cdot0.97^{16}=0.03299\cdots\\\cdots$$

This approach will cost you $7$ squarings, then $6$ products, i.e. $13$ multiplies. Unfortunately, this is painful and error prone by hand, and it is an uneasy question to know how many decimals you need to keep.

An alternative is by brute force: as you need to compute powers of $0.97=1-0.03$, the multiply is easy: subtract the multiplicand times $3$, shifted right by two positions. In the given case, you will need to perform $115$ multiplies, but they are relatively easy. This might beat the previous approach.

Of course you can evaluate the logarithms by Taylor series, but to implement this method you will need to know the value of a constant such as $\ln(10)$ or $\ln(2)$ depending on the base you will use.